# Windows phone Audio play back Agent

Tags: windows-phone-8, audio-playback-agent

Can anybody please tell me that how to play dynamic music list using background playback agent in windows phone 8,i search every where on internet but tutorials can use tha hard coded music list

Answer (score 0):

You can write the information about the music list from the UI (main app) to a file in Isolated storage and then read that information into a List of `AudioTrack` from the Background Audio Playback Agent.